# html2canvas is not reading inline background-color style

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas which works great except the background colour of the div is not being read when I use inline styling. However it does work when a style sheet is used, but as the colour is controlled by react, I need it to read the inline style preferably, can anyone help fix this pls?

My html:

```
<div id="testDiv" class="page" style="width: 530px; height: 630px; background-color: red; position: relative;">...</div>
```

My js:

```
function getThumbnail = (div) => {
  return html2canvas(div).then(canvas => {
    return canvas.toDataURL();
  });
}
```

The image is rendered with no background in the above code unless I add:

```
#testDiv {
  background-color: red;
}
```

in a style sheet but then it is not easy to make the background variable.

UPDATE: I've also tried using css variables but html2canvas does not pick up this styling either.

```
:root {
  --garment-colour: #000000;
};

#testDiv {
  background-color: var(--garment-colour);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does show the background. See console log for image data.

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#testDiv")).then(canvas => {
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxrvsphz/

Comment: Ah yes, so it does. Thank you. It was not the inline style in the end it was the fact it was in rgb and not hex.

Comment: Actually scrap that. It was the rendering of my app, and html2canvas taking longer than expected.